# Why can't a function that returns `some View` return any type of View?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to learn the nuances of SwiftUI.

In the following function, if I use a guard to catch the case where my `SwipeDirection` parameter is nil and return a rectangle that's only stroked, not filled I get a compiler error that "Function declares an opaque return type 'some View', but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types."

```
func boxForDirection(_ direction: SwipeDirection?) -> some View {
    guard let direction else {
        return Rectangle()
//            .fill(.clear) // <- Commenting out this line causes the error.
            .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    return Rectangle()
        .fill(colorForDirection(direction))
        .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

If I un-comment the `.fill()` modifier on the guard statement, the error goes away.

So I gather that:

1. A return type of "some View" does not mean **any** object of type View, but that the function will always return a specific type of view.
2. A Rectangle with the `.fill()` modifier is a different type of View than a Rectangle that only has the `.stroke()` modifier.

**Q:** Why are both of those things true? I would expect that a return type of `some View` means that the function can return any object that is of type `View`.

Further, I would think that a `Rectangle` is `Rectangle`, whether it's filled or not.

**Q:** Is there a way to have a function return any view type? Or maybe any variant of a Rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Why are both of those things true?

My understanding of `some View` is that the compiler must be able to work out exactly which view it is. So if you have multiple return statements, they must return the same type. And yes, every modifier probably wraps the view in another type, so a filled rectangle will probably not be the same as a stroked rectangle.

> Q2: Is there a way to have a function return any view type?

Yes. You can implement the function as a `ViewBuilder`. This requires using `if-else` instead of having `return` statements:

```swift
@ViewBuilder
func boxForDirection(_ direction: SwipeDirection?) -> some View {
    if let direction {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(colorForDirection(direction))
            .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    } else {
        Rectangle()
            // .fill(.clear) // no problem if commented
            .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benzy. I'd love to understand the formal definitions of things like `some View` and `@viewBuilder`. Do you know of any good write-ups?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! Here are some links to Apple docs: [Opaque and Boxed Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/opaquetypes), [ViewBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder)